# Hibernate JDBCConnection cannot open connection error with H2 database

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, junit

I am new to Java and Enterprise development, and currently I am trying to implement some JUnit tests incorporating *Hibernate* by creating an in-memory database using H2.

I found a [tutorial online](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2011/03/13/testing-databases-with-junit-and-hibernate-part-1-one-to-rule-them/) dealing with this and have integrated some of this code. I have a feeling the following code that may be responsible for the specific error I am seeing:

> org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection

```
 private SessionFactory createSessionFactory() 
    {
        AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Facility.class);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.h2.Driver");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:mem");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;  
    }
```

I have downloaded H2 and added the JAR to my build path, and I know Hibernate is configured correctly besides this because when I run Junit tests using our already set up development database, the tests execute successfully without any connection errors. The configuration file for that is in a separate file called hibernate.properties, consisting of following:

```
 hibernate.connection.datasource=java:/jdbc/mysql
 hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
 hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
 hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this error?

This is my first post, so if anyone needs more information or clarification, please let me know.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is the stack trace

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:mem
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at com.cmt.test.SessionFactoryRule.createSessionFactory(SessionFactoryRule.java:73)
    at com.cmt.test.SessionFactoryRule.access$0(SessionFactoryRule.java:64)
    at com.cmt.test.SessionFactoryRule$1.evaluate(SessionFactoryRule.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at com.cmt.test.TestRunner.runTest(TestRunner.java:57)
    at com.cmt.test.bean.TestBean.runTestCase(TestBean.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:170)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1092)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:791)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1256)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
14:12:12,044 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
14:12:12,044 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:mem
14:12:12,046 INFO  [STDOUT] DEBUG - Failure :  
    Cannot open connection 
    CreateFacility(com.cmt.test.memory.InMemoryTest) 
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1353)
    at com.cmt.test.SessionFactoryRule.beginTransaction(SessionFactoryRule.java:89)
    at com.cmt.test.SessionFactoryRule$1.evaluate(SessionFactoryRule.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at com.cmt.test.TestRunner.runTest(TestRunner.java:57)
    at com.cmt.test.bean.TestBean.runTestCase(TestBean.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:170)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1092)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:791)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1256)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:mem
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 74 more

    CreateFacility(com.cmt.test.memory.InMemoryTest) 
    Cannot open connection 
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Your JDBC URL must end with a colon: `"jdbc:h2:mem:"`.

Comment: I added the colon but am still getting the connection errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the driver is not registered properly. Try calling this right at the beginning of your create session factory method:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
```

or

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:", "sa", "");
```

We're using H2 for unit tests as well and doing some pre-init work calling the latter - this registers the Driver (implicitly).

Comment: Hey PepperBob, I tried both approaches and in the stack trace got the same error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:mem:

Comment: Are you sure that the library is on the classpath?

Comment: Yeah, I just removed it from build path(it had been referenced from a folder that was different from my current project's), copied into my current folder. then re-added jar to build path to make sure, but still got error

Comment: Thanks so much PepperBob! I added both lines you suggested, and after cleaning the server, together they work

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just starting out I suggest starting simple.  Create a class with a main method like below.  If you run this and you don't see the system out print, then the H2 driver isn't on your classpath.  If this works, understand how to apply the connection parameters to the Hibernate config.

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:", "sa", "");
    System.out.println("woohoo!  connected.");
    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a good idea Steve. I made a separate class with only that main method, and when I try to run the class as a java application, I get "Could not find the main class: <package_name>.class. Program will exit. I have a feeling I am missing something obvious.. but I can't figure out what it is...

Comment: Sounds like you haven't compiled your class.  If you aren't using an IDE, you need to use javac to compile the .java file into a .class file, then you can run your class with java.